# c# SqlBulkCopy keeps making my first column the primary key

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, sqlbulkcopy

I am using `SqlBulkCopy` in a loop to upload a number of Excel sheets into a `DataTable`, and I cannot make it stop imposing primary key status on the first column in the sheets (unhelpfully called `Id`), which does not contain unique values and therefore triggers a duplicate key error.

`SqlBulkCopyOptions` does not have `KeepIdentity` set; I have tried specifying 2 columns as primary keys; or an additional column at either the beginning or end of the columns as a primary key. But as soon as i run the program it resets the structure of my `DataTable`, makes the first column primary key and falls over.

I am using column mappings.

```
foreach (String file in ValidFiles)
{
    //string strConnection = "Data Source=MySystem;Initial Catalog=MySamplesDB;Integrated Security=True";

    string strConnection = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Rep004Filter.Properties.Settings.Database1ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;            
    string excelConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + file + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;Persist Security Info=False;";

    OleDbConnection excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString);
    excelConnection.Open();
    dtSchema = excelConnection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" });

    Sheet1 = dtSchema.Rows[0].Field<string>("TABLE_NAME");
    Debug.WriteLine("Sheet name: " + Sheet1);

    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select * from [" + Sheet1 + "]", excelConnection);
    OleDbDataReader dReader;

    dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    SqlBulkCopy sqlBulk = new SqlBulkCopy(strConnection);
    sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Id", "Id");              
    ... lots more column mappings here...
    sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Src", "Src");

    sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = "dbo.[Table]";
    sqlBulk.WriteToServer(dReader);
    excelConnection.Close();             
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The ID column is *already* a primary key in the database table. SqlBulkCopy doesn't make any modifications to the table schema. What is the table's schema? Also why do you mention `KeepIdentity`? An Identity column isn't a primary key, it's just an autoincrementic column.

Comment: There is no `DataTable` in your code either. In any case, a DataTable is just an in-memory type. It doesn't get reset, it gets created again each time you call `new`

Comment: Thank you, i did not know the KeepIdentity was an auto increment. I shall look more closely at how I'm feeding into the datatable.  I have created the table separately with additional columns, but I'm obviously not referencing it properly.  The confusing thing was that the program was overwriting my exiting table with the new structure, if it had created a separate table i might have realized they were different.  Thank you very much for the pointers.